# Convert byte array to Spark column

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark-sql

How do I convert a byte array to an `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`?

For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
...

def toColumn(bytes: Array[Byte]): Column = {
  // todo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lit` should do the job:

```
def toColumn(bytes: Array[Byte]): Column = {
    lit(bytes)
}

val df = spark.range(1)

df.withColumn("byte", toColumn(Array[Byte](1,1,1,1))).show
+---+-------------+
| id|         byte|
+---+-------------+
|  0|[01 01 01 01]|
+---+-------------+
```